# How to reaload (refill) jqGrid data from an ajax reponse (from a Struts 2 action)?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2

I have this code just to send data from already loaded jqGrid:

```
jQuery("#bedata").click(function(){ //Function for button "bedata"

 var postData = "SOME DATA TO SEND"

//Sending data:
$.ajax({
    type: "POST";
    url: "GuardaFila.action", //Action called to data treatament (Struts 2)
    data : {
        jgGridData: postData, //PARAMETER jgGrdData with variable "postData" value
        customData: "someinfo" //Just another parameter called "customData" with more data,
    },

    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",

//Success function has the key that I am looking for:
    success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
        //SOME CODE HERE TO REFILL jqGrid.
        alert("success");
     },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error");
    }

});
});
```

jqGrid has been created before this way:

```
  jQuery("#rowed3").jqGrid({
                url:'CargaTabla.action',
                datatype: "json",
                colNames:['id', 'Direccion', 'Nombre'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
                    {name:'direccion',index:'direccion', width:90, editable:true},
                    {name:'nombre',index:'nombre', width:100,editable:true}
                ],
                jsonReader: {
                    root: 'gridModel',
                    id: '0',
                    cell :"",
                    repeatitems: false
                },


(....... etc)
```

So, id for jqGrid table is #rowed3. I know that in the ajax function:

```
        success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
        //SOME CODE HERE TO REFILL jqGrid.
        alert("success");
     },
```

response parameter has a the new content in JSON for the grid. I tried some ways to refill the grid with its data as setting its "datastr" parameter with its content and others. Has someone faced before this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel here. jqGrid already knows how to fetch data, so you don't need to call `$.ajax`. Just change the grid params and tell it to do its thing (from memory; correct function names if need be, but this will give you the idea):

```
var opts = { url: "GuardaFila.action", postData: postData };
grid.setGridParam(opts);
grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Comment: Heya folks. Thank you both for your reply. Yes, Its true, jqGrid already knows from where get its data, but I need to do an ajax callig to send data from grid to server in order to upgrade database. I am making an ajax call, and I want to use its reponse to refill grid. Not calling the action (url) to do that. The action its done once ajax call has been done.

Comment: Thank you, It worked =) with var grid = jQuery("#rowed3"); Thank you both. Its more simple than that, with your help, my ActionClass is autoupdatable at server too. Im really sorry, I cant score you, yet, I need 15 score for that :(. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for `grid.addJSONData` method.

For example:

```
success: function (data, textStatus) {
    if (textStatus == "success") {
       var grid = $("#rowed3")[0];
       grid.addJSONData(JSON.parse(data.d));
   }
},
```

Keep in mind that you need to make sure your JSON data format matches what is specified in the JSON reader.

Comment: That could work, but it will break other grid functions (e.g., paging, search), since the grid is still configured for the old URL, etc.

Comment: @Craig this is true! grid.trigger("reloadGrid"); is a simpler solution if that is all that is needed.  +1 :)

Comment: $("#rowed3")[0] is an HTMLTable in my debuggin. How can I get again the jqGrid as an object?

Comment: Maybe var grid = jQuery("#rowed3"); instead?

Comment: var grid = jQuery("#rowed3") instead var grid = $("#rowed3")[0]; worked for me. I am really sorry, i cannot score you yet :-(

Comment: @Yuck Ty. I cannot understand $("rowed3")[0] instead jQuery("#rowed3"), but it seems its working. Thank you. First way is a kinda strange for me.

Comment: @Raph Sorry, not sure why it is different for you, I copied an example that I use and it also shows it that way in the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods).  Glad you got it working though!